# What kind of phrase is it?

Tags: grammaticality

> There is no island in the world **as big as Greenland.**

In the sentence, what kind of phrase is **'as big as Greenland'**? Does it modify the word **'island'**?

Comment: “As big as Greenland” is an adjectival phrase functioning as a comparative **complement** to “island”. The phrase is analysed as adv-adj-prep-noun, with the adjective “big” as head of the phrase and Greenland as an noun functioning as complement to the prep “as”. An alternative analysis is to take “Greenland” as a reduced comparative clause so that the structure is like that of “There is no island in the world as big as Greenland is”.

Comment: I give another alternative: reduced form of *There is no island in the world which is as big as Greenland.*

Answer (score 1):

Your example

> as big as Greenland

is a **simile** where *like* or *as* are used to make comparisons.